# Error in checkData(data) : Only numeric data allowed

Tags: r, numeric, error-code

I am trying to run the `cpt.mean` function from the `changepoint package`. After first trying to run it on my dataframe `df2` it gives me an error:

My data frame `df2` looks like this:

```
    date     amount
2012-07-01   0.0000000
2012-08-01   1.1111111
2012-09-01   0.2985075
2012-10-01   0.5141388
2012-11-01   0.0000000
2012-12-01   0.0000000
2013-01-01   0.6849315
2013-02-01   1.9762846
2013-03-01   1.1799410
2013-04-01   0.2881844
2013-05-01   0.2617801
2013-06-01   1.2285012
```

My code:

```
df2 <- data.frame(df1$date,df1$amount))
df2.pelt <- cpt.mean(df2, method="PELT")
```

> Error in checkData(data) : Only numeric data allowed

So I did this:

```
df2 <- data.frame(as.numeric(df2$date),as.numeric(df2$amount))
```

And my new data frame looks like this:

```
 date        amount
15522      0.0000000
15553      1.1111111
15584      0.2985075
15614      0.5141388
15645      0.0000000
15675      0.0000000
15706      0.6849315
15737      1.9762846
15765      1.1799410
15796      0.2881844
15826      0.2617801
15857      1.2285012
```

I try to run my cpt.mean function again, the same error comes up.
Then I see what classes my columns are with this:

```
> class(df2$date.)
[1] "numeric"
> class(df2$amount.)
[1] "numeric"
```

Both times I get "numeric" as the result, but cpt.means still doesnt run.

What am I missing? Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Does the answer help you?

Answer (score 0):

In [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/changepoint/versions/2.2.2/topics/cpt.mean), it is highlighted about the `data` feature:

> data
>
> A vector, ts object or matrix containing the data within which
>   you wish to find a changepoint. If data is a matrix, each row is
>   considered a separate dataset.

So, as it says, your data supposed to be **vector**, **matrix**, or **time series object**.

But if you run the `class(df2)` it gives you a `data.frame`.

Here is a small sample of runing this function with a vector:

```
library(changepoint)    
x=c(rnorm(100,0,1),rnorm(100,10,1))
cpt.mean(x,penalty="SIC",method="AMOC",class=FALSE)
```